# How to create native executable using quarkus?

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I've created a quarkus application using quarkus maven plugin.

My maven pom is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-poc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
        <quarkus.version>0.11.0</quarkus.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Beta5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>native-image</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemProperties>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                    </systemProperties>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

But when i try to create a native build using `mvn package -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true` I get the following error message, independently of the platform.

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:0.11.0:native-image (default) @ quarkus-poc ---
[INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
[INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] docker run -v C:\Users\nicolas-delsaux\Documents\Adeo\inhabitant-referential--api-poc-challenge\quarkus\target:/project:z --rm swd847/centos-graal-native-image-rc12 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -jar quarkus-poc-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -J-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -H:+PrintAnalysisCallTree -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-SpawnIsolates -H:-JNI -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace
Error: No main manifest attribute, in /project/quarkus-poc-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  27.308 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-12T16:11:43+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.11.0:native-image (default) on project quarkus-poc: Failed to generate a native image: Failed to build native image: Image generation failed -> [Help 1]
```

I do recognize that I have not created any kind of main class, since quarkus doesn't seems to need it. But how can i declare to the Java platform that I plan to let quarkus decide of the main class ?

**EDIT** In response to c. tweet, here are some more infos

The `-runner.jar` content is

```
+---com
|   \---company
|       \---service
|           \---domain
|               \---poc
|                       Customer.class
|                       CustomerService.class
|                       CustomerService_Bean.class
|                       CustomersResource.class
|                       CustomersResource_Bean.class
|
+---io
|   \---quarkus
|       +---arc
|       |   |   ActivateRequestContextInterceptor_Bean.class
|       |   |
|       |   +---runtime
|       |   |       LifecycleEventRunner_Bean.class
|       |   |
|       |   \---setup
|       |           Default_ComponentsProvider.class
|       |
|       +---deployment
|       |   \---steps
|       |           ArcAnnotationProcessor$build4.class
|       |           LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent9.class
|       |           LoggingResourceProcessor$setupLoggingRuntimeInit1.class
|       |           LoggingResourceProcessor$setupLoggingRuntimeInit2.class
|       |           LoggingResourceProcessor$setupLoggingStaticInit1.class
|       |           LoggingResourceProcessor$setupLoggingStaticInit2.class
|       |           ResteasyScanningProcessor$setupInjection5.class
|       |           ResteasyScanningProcessor$setupInjection6.class
|       |           UndertowArcIntegrationBuildStep$integrateRequestContext5.class
|       |           UndertowArcIntegrationBuildStep$integrateRequestContext6.class
|       |           UndertowBuildStep$boot8.class
|       |           UndertowBuildStep$build7.class
|       |
|       +---runner
|       |       ApplicationImpl1.class
|       |       AutoFeature.class
|       |       GeneratedMain.class
|       |
|       \---runtime
|           \---generated
|                   ConfigHelper.class
|                   ConfigHelperData.class
|                   ConfigRoot.class
|
+---javax
|   \---enterprise
|       \---context
|           \---control
|                   ActivateRequestContext_Shared_AnnotationLiteral.class
|
\---META-INF
    |   MANIFEST.MF
    |   microprofile-config.properties
    |   quarkus-default-config.properties
    |
    +---maven
    |   \---com
    |       \---quarkus-poc
    |               pom.properties
    |               pom.xml
    |
    +---resources
    |       index.html
    |
    \---services
            io.quarkus.arc.ComponentsProvider
```

I'm quite sure some of you will ask for MANIFEST.MF content

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: nicolas-delsaux
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

I think that manifest file is quite strange ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that eclipse has auto-created a manifest file for you, and we are not dealing with this situation correctly. Depending on how the manifest has been added running 'mvn clean package' might fix it, or there may me a MANIFEST.MF file in 'src/main/resources' that needs to be removed.

I have filed https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1443 to improve the way we handle this.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of additional unrelated comments:

- you can use the `resteasy-jsonb` extension instead of Jackson
- if you really want Jackson, the version should be defined in our BOM and you can drop yours (in any case, it's not the right one)
- we now recommend to use `src/main/resources/application.properties` for your config file (we fixed the project creation recently)
- you don't need the `quarkus-arc` dependency
- you should define the scope of `quarkus-junit5` to be `test`. For now, it's covered by the BOM but we will change that soon.

Comment: why is the quarkus-arc dependency not needed anymore?