# run quarkus app gradlew quarkusBuild with some profile

Tags: quarkus

`./gradlew quarkusBuild` [creates a jar](https://quarkus.io/guides/gradle-tooling) (`1.0.1 Final`)

**Q:** How to run it from with some profile/env ?

```
java -jar -Dquarkus-profile=dev build/my-project-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

or

```
java -jar -Dquarkus-profile=dev build/libs/my-project-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**ERROR:**

> no main manifest attribute, in 
>   `build/my-project-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124900/how-to-create-native-executable-using-quarkus). I do not have META-INF in my src/main/resources

if relevant, In `application.properites`:

```
quarkus.package.uber-jar=true  // tried with true & false
```

Comment: You have to execute the `-runner.jar` (unless you have changed its name)

Comment: Also note that dev is a specific profile in Quarkus related to dev mode, you should probably use another name.

Comment: I did change the name.